# PostgreSQL convert date with timezone to a timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have date stored in format `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZ` (datetime with timezone) in my psql database. I need to convert this date to a timestamp.

I tried to_timestamp() but it is not working with timezone.

```
ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date
```

I tried ::timestamptz but it consider date to be in format of `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI TZ`

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range
```

Is there any way to convert the format from `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZ` to `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI TZ` or convert `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZ` to timestamp?

e.g. "28/04/2017 13:00 +2:30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try casting directly?..

```
so=# select to_timestamp('04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30','D/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZ');
ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date
Time: 20.850 ms
so=# select '04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2017-04-28 10:30:00+00
(1 row)

Time: 0.554 ms
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

> to_timestamp and to_date exist to handle input formats that cannot be
>   converted by simple casting. For most standard date/time formats,
>   simply casting the source string to the required data type works, and
>   is much easier.

**update**

regarding your comment, you just need to adjust `datestyle` to change the parsing:

```
so=# set datestyle to DMY;
SET
Time: 9.997 ms
so=# select '04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30'::timestamptz;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30"
LINE 1: select '04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30'::timestamptz;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
Time: 10.217 ms
so=# set datestyle to MDY;
SET
Time: 8.799 ms
so=# select '04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2017-04-28 10:30:00+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the description my date is in the format of DD/MM/YYYY thus select '28/04/2017 13:00 +2:30'::timestamptz, will give error date/time field value out of range.

Comment: @ayushlodhi updated the answer - jut set datestyle for parser to know what it should expect

Comment: @VaosTsun thanks for your answer, so every time I will have to use set datestyle to MDY; before querying over this, isn't there any alternative like to_timestamp('04/28/2017 13:00 +2:30','D/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZ')?

Comment: to_timestamp and to_date do not support TZ, so you have to either set datestyle on session level or user level or database level or cluster level. I showed you how to do it on session level - once set all next querries will use new config until you disconnect. if you set it globally you will have it after reconnecting.